# Decomposition of additive time series

Tags: r, cbind, decomposition

[Hey, I am sorry if this question might be too easy for this forum! My task was to decompose a time series to break it into the different components. Then plot it in R.
However, the correct solutions included the part that I uploaded as a picture. We are trying to identify the monthly data right? but why are we using the cbind and the data.frame function? than you very much in advance[enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfCn2.png) ][2]

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible code?

Comment: series_decomposed <- decompose(series, type = "additive", filter = c(1/24, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/24))

Comment: plot(series_decomposed)

seasonal_coef <- data.frame(series_decomposed$figure)
seasonal_coef <- cbind(seasonal_coef, seq(1:12))
seasonal_coef[order(-seasonal_coef[,1]),]

Comment: series_decomposed.figure seq(1:12)
12             10563.041811        12
11              1476.034867        11
8                499.173547         8
5                  8.889034         5
10              -553.015480        10
3               -682.180411         3
4               -798.640480         4
7              -1136.711453         7
6              -1190.076244         6
9              -1399.694300         9
2              -2653.038050         2
1              -4133.782841         1

Comment: Like this? Or should I upload an R file?